# Realm crash from invalid objects when application/viewcontroller leaves foreground

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a `MainViewController` that has a reference to an array of objects that extend Realm's `Object`.

I noticed the array of Realm objects are becoming invalid in a very specific scenario.

1. `MainViewController` receives a notification such as internet connection has changed.
2. Press the home button to put the app into the background.
3. The target function for the notification observer is executed and tries to access the array of Realm objects.
4. All the objects are invalid and causes the app to crash.

Is the reason the app is crashing, is because Realm objects cannot be accessed while the app/viewcontroller is not in view?

I have checked the app and the array of objects are not being deleted/modified during these actions.

Comment: Post the code so that we can see.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs for `isInvalidated`

> An object can no longer be accessed if the object has been deleted from the Realm that manages it, or if invalidate() is called on that Realm.

Since you already confirmed the objects aren't deleted, then it's possible something is calling `invalidate()` on the realm. Make sure you're not calling that somewhere.

If it's still occurring, try creating a small sample project to show off the issue and submit it as a bug to Realm. They're pretty responsive to bug reports with a project that shows of the issue.